# Selenium cant find element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<input class="form__input number-verify" type="tel" id="sms-number" maxlength="20">

tel = browser.find_element(By.ID , "form__input number-verify")
```

It's not working. I want to click that element and then write (ı know how do it) but ı cant solve my problem.

and that all code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
browser = webdriver.Edge()
browser.get("https://globfone.com/send-text/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
giris_yap = browser.find_element(By.NAME,"sender-name")
giris_yap.click()
giris_yap.send_keys("abc")
next_button = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "cover__btn")
next_button.click()
time.sleep(5)
tel = browser.find_element(By.ID , "form__input number-verify")

time.sleep(5)
browser.close()
```

Comment: We can't guess why it is wot working for you. There are a lot of possible things that can cause that. We need to see all your Selenium code and a page (link) you working on to understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main mistake is that `form__input number-verify` is not ID, these are 2 class values, so you can use CSS Selector or Xpath to use these 2 class names.
Also, you should not use hardcoded pauses. `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` should be used instead.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

url = 'https://globfone.com/send-text/'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

giris_yap = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "sender-name")))
giris_yap.click()
giris_yap.send_keys("abc")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "cover__btn"))).click()
tel = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form__input.number-verify")))
tel.send_keys("755")
```

the result is:

[image]